# JQuery - Sending extra parameters to callback function

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, parameters

When using the $.ajax() function for sending a request for information from server-side scripting, can you pass parameters to the callback function?

Example:

```
var params = ['param1', 'param2', 'param3']; 
for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(json, textStatus, jqXHR){
            console.log(params[i]);             
        }
    });
}
```

but it doesnt work. do you have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `params` and `i` exist in the global namespace, so each `success` will get you the last value of `i`, assuming the AJAX call takes longer than the for loop (boy, it better).

Wrap your AJAX call in a function and pass the parameter into the function. You can then call it directly from inside `success`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass it to your url using the `data` option then return it in the response, thus having it in the async success callback.

By the way you should probably wrap  the entire ajax bit in a function outside the `for` loop and call it from within the loop. Like this

```
var params = ['param1', 'param2', 'param3']; 

function do_stuff(param){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            'param' : param
        },
        success: function(json, textStatus, jqXHR){
            console.log(json.param);    
        }
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
  do_stuff(params[i]);
}
```

Comment: your URL needs to return json! and it needs to return the data value